# How to execute multiple tasks in one child process in fork()

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork

how to do multi-threading for this function with dynamic no of threads specified by the user

Comment: If you want a child process to create 50 images,why not make it loop 50 times?

Comment: You are forking in a nested loop.  So while your outer loop decrements by the value of x each time, the inner loop then forks x times, so you'll make all forks.  I suspect you would probably really want an initial loop to create your x forks and then have each of those forks loop through and do their thing.

Comment: How can you tell the child process after it is launched to create 50 images?  I don't think you can — the command line tells it how to create one image, and you need a new command line for each image, so you have to create as many child processes as you have images.  Or you have to rewrite (extend) the `mandel` program to read a series of specifications from a file (or standard input), creating one image for each specification, or something along those lines.  IOW, I think that what you've got is close to what you need – what you want is not attainable with the information available to us.

Comment: Note: 0...50 would be 51 images.

Comment: the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements for `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h` and `unistd.h`

Comment: immediately after a call to `fork()` there can be 3 different conditions.  1) the call failed (returned value is -1)  2) the returned value is 0 (in child process) 3) the returned value is >0 (in parent process).   Your code is not checking for those three conditions,

Comment: the nested `for()` statements are nonsense.  For instance, what happens of the user enters 0?  what happens if the user enters 1?  what happens if the user enters 2?

Comment: the posted code contains a 'magic' number.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 50.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name.  Then using that meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  Names like 'x' are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: the array 'argarry[]' is always in the same location in memory, and always contains the same values (other than the 'str[]' entry) so 1) all the child processes will be using the same memory so will 'see' what ever the latest values in the 'argarryp[]' contains. AND due to timing, etc will not necessarily see what the values were when the child process was created.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  In the posted code, the call to 'scanf()' should be: `if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &num ) ) { perror( "scanf failed" );`

Comment: the posted code is failing to wait for all the child processes to be completed before the `main` process exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. incorporates the comments to the OPs question
2. cleanly compiles
3. demonstrates how perform a counted loop
4. demonstrates how to check for errors returned from system functions `malloc()` and `scanf()`
5. demonstrates how to handle the returned value from `fork()`
6. demonstrates how to avoid 'magic' numbers
7. documents why each header file is included

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // printf(), scanf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <unistd.h>   // fork(), execvp()
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> // waitpid()


// prototypes
void mandelseries(int);


#define MAX_STR_LEN  15
#define ARRAY_SIZE   16


void mandelseries(int numImages)
{
    pid_t child[ numImages ];

    for( int i = 0; i < numImages; i++ )
    {
        child[i] = fork();
        switch( child[i] )
        {
            case -1:
                perror( "fork failed" );;
                break;

            case 0:   // child
                {
                    char **argarry = malloc( ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof( char* ) );
                    if( !argarry )
                    {
                        perror( "malloc for arg array failed" );
                        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                    }

                    // implied else, malloc successful

                    // ... fill in arguments here

                    execvp( argarry[0], argarry);
                    perror( "execvp failed" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }
                break;

            default:   // parent
                break;
        } // end switch()
    }

    for( int i=0; i < numImages; i++ )
    {
        int status;

        if( -1 != child[i] )
        {
            waitpid(child[i], &status, 0);
        }
    }
}


int main( void )
{
    int numImages;
    printf("Enter number of times:");

    if( 1 != scanf("%d", &numImages) )
    {
        perror( "scanf failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    mandelseries(numImages);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Not each header, you left `<sys/types.h>` feeling lonely without comment :)

Comment: @JustMe  The MAN page says to include <sys/types.h>  I'm not sure why.